# laravel request validation rules pass parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm going straight to the point here, I am wondering if it is possible to pass a parameter on a `validation rule` in Laravel.

Here's my code:

I need to pass the `$product->id` to the `ProductUpdateRequest` class.

I've read some articles and to no avail can't pass a parameter into it. my other solution was to not use the validation rule class and do the validation directly on the controller by using `$request->validate[()]`. Since I can access the `$product->id` on the controller I can easily do the validation. but out of curiosity is there a way for me to pass the `$product->id` on the `validation class`?

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function update(ProductUpdateRequest $request, Product $product)
    {
        $request['detail'] = $request->description;
        unset($request['description']);
        $product->update($request->all());

        return response([
            'data' => new ProductResource($product)
        ], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

**VALIDATION RULE**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:products,name'.$product->id,
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required|numeric|max:500',
        'stock' => 'required|max:6',
        'discount' => 'required:max:2'
    ];
}
```

Any suggestions/answers/help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: some validation rules like unique, and exists have an option param. 
Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: hi @bmatovu here's should be my validation rule `return[
            'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:products,name'.$product->id]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the resolved binding from request

```
$product = $this->route('product');
```

Inside your `rules` method you can get the product instance with the above method.

```
public function rules()
{
    $product = $this->route('product');
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:products,name'.$product->id,
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required|numeric|max:500',
        'stock' => 'required|max:6',
        'discount' => 'required:max:2'
    ];
}
```

It works when you make a function with this Product $product (when you used the Resource route in most cases)
public function update(ProductUpdateRequest $request, Product $product)
{
// code goes here
}

but if you make it like the below it won't work ()
public function update(ProductUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
// code goes here
}

Comment: Do you get any errors. 'product' should match the route parameter name.

Comment: Hi sir Error: `Undefined variable: request`

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Change `$request` to `$this`

Comment: It's route model binding. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: This does work! You are the man! :-) (at least in Laravel 5.7)

Comment: what is the 'product' in the route('product')?

Comment: @MDB It's the name of url parameter

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would validate unique product name on update. I pass the product ID as a route parameter, the use the [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique) validation rule to validate that it the product **name** does't exist in the Database *except* for this product (id).

```
class ProductController extends Controller {

    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:products,name'.$id,
        ]);

        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi sir.. this is my other solution.... but u think it is possible to do it on my `Validation Class`?

Comment: Ohhhh... I was wondering too, you have the solution. The question wasn't as clear. Sorry

`my validation class`, why not just rule a new validation rule, then use your custom validation logic?

Answer (score 1):

For custom request in validation rule you can put  in your
View :

```
<input type="hidden" value="product_id">
```

In Validation Request :

```
public function rules()
{
    $product_id = $this->request->get('product_id');

    return [
      //
    ];
}
```